# Jersey Client forgets Accept headers on redirect

Tags: redirect, http-headers, client, jersey

I'm trying to use Jersey as a client for a RESTful application. Specifically I'd like to `POST` some JSON to the server and get JSON back, so my code looks like this:

```
final JSONObject config = new JSONObject();
clientConfig.put("fooParam", 60 * 5); /* 5 min timeout */

final JSONObject newClient = client.resource(/* URL */).
                          type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                          accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                          post(JSONObject.class, config);
```

this generates the expected HTTP request with the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers set appropriately. Now the server decides the create the requested resource and *redirects* there using a `HTTP/1.1 303 See Other` response (which is good practice as far as I know). The good news is that Jersey happily picks up the `Location` header and indeed requests the resource it was told to. The bad thing is that it seems to have forgot that I only wanted to get `application/json` resources and sends a `GET` with

```
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

which the server answers happily (with perfectly legal HTML). I verified this using Wireshark. The problem is that Jersey blows up on this as it can not parse this into a `JSONObject`. So my question is

- Is that behaviour of Jersey correct or rather a bug?
- Is there some *clever* way around this?

I'm aware that I could possibly go through Jersey's [`ClientResponse`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.7/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html) class and see if I was redirected myself, but I think there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like a bug in the Jersey client library to me. I would check to make sure you're using the latest version, then ask about it on their mailing list.

Comment: I sent this to the jersey-issues mailing list (not sure if this was the right list, though): http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/issues/archive/2011-06/message/54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [short conversation](http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/issues/archive/2011-06/message/54) with Pavel on a Jersey mailing list, it seems as if the problem lies withing the `HttpURLConnection` class from the Java libraries. Working around this is easy by using the Apache HTTP Client library [binding for Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-apache-client4/index.html), which works nicely.